# JNI Global Static Variables in C++ Code

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, global-variables

I have a JNI C++ code being called from a multi-threaded java application

This C++ code has 2 global static variables a boolean and a string.

For some reason i keep getting segmentation fault from this code . Any idea what could lead to this ? I know this is not thread safe, but i am treating the variables as read only from the java application and only the C++ code is able to modify the values of these variables

Help much appreciated

EDIT : This code runs on a Linux machine . And runs for months at a time without any issues, then it issues a signal 11 segmentation fault and the JVM crashes.

Comment: so you're sure the C++ code which modifies the variables does not interfere with the Java code reading them?

Comment: Are you sure that a bug that crashes the program once every few months is worth hunting down?

Comment: When you have a large number of these machines spread all over the world and they tackle a mission critical task , it is a big problem :)

Comment: add some sanity checks, e.g. make sure nothing modifies the string during the C++ call by forcibly checking length on every line etc. you should quickly be able to tell if something is stomping these variables somehow which leads to the seg fault. e.g http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_byte

Answer (score 5):

If you're calling the C++ code from multiple threads, and the C++ code has global static variables, then it would be amazing if it worked. The simplest thing to try is to put a lock around the call, i.e. in the Java side change

```
native int callToCppFunction(int parameter);
```

to

```
synchronized native int callToCppFunction(int parameter);
```

to ensure that only one thread can be in the C++ code at a time.

Then there's another possible issue, which I bumped on about a year ago: apparently in Windows dlls it may not be enough to serialize calls to it (i.e. use `synchronized`). They may also require to be called *from the same thread each time*. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157836/invoking-time-consuming-jni-task-as-a-thread/3830487#3830487) answer offers an explanation to how that can be. The solution is to make a single threaded executor to the Java side, and route all calls to the native code through it.

Comment: Thanks for the response . It runs for a long period of time, sometimes for months without any problems , then it seg faults at random. It is on a Linux machine  just for added info .

Comment: Random seg faults are a pain to debug, especially if they happen quite rarely. They *could* be due to threading, but as well they could be due to something else. The last resort may be to add some logging: log the state of variables and threads at all moments, and you'll see what are the program's "last words". Maybe you'll find something there. Good luck!